# Using Array from another Class - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays

Im new to Objective and iPad apps. 
Im trying to display an array that Ive already used in a separate Class/View Controller.
The array Im trying to access is in "MainMenuScreen.m" and I want to use that array in another class called "ScoresScreen.m".
Ive searched online and It seems to come back with something called Segue? I was going through examples but I keep getting errors and not sure what to do. Surely there has to be an easy way to get an array from a different class and display it? 
I did try doing this at the beginning of "ScoresScreen.m" - Import "MainMenuScreen.m", but I get an error when trying to call the array from it. All my code is working, I just need to get the array from the other class and plug into my code.
I dont expect you to do the code for me, but please tell me how I would go about using an array from a different class?
Thankyou in advance

---

This is the code for ScoresScreen.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ScoresScreen : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
     NSMutableArray *scoresArray;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;


@end
```

---

This is ScoresScreen.m code =

```
#import "ScoresScreen.h"
#import "MainMenuScreen.h"




@interface ScoresScreen ()

@end

@implementation ScoresScreen

NSMutableArray *TestScoresArray;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    TestScoresArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];//test data

    [TestScoresArray addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name : Bob",@" | Score : 134", nil]];//testData
    [TestScoresArray addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name : Roger",@" | Score : 12",nil]];//testData
    [TestScoresArray addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name : Ben",@"| Score : 34",nil]];//testData
    [super viewDidLoad];



    for(NSMutableArray *m in TestScoresArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@%@", m[0],m[1]);
   }

}

- (void)addNewScore
{

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}
-  (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 6;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }



NSLog(@"%@",scoresArray);

    NSString *continent;
   NSMutableArray *country = [scoresArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    continent =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[country objectAtIndex:0],[country objectAtIndex:1]];
cell.textLabel.text = continent;

 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

 return cell;
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setTableView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

---

This is code for MainMenuScreen.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainMenuScreen : UIViewController

- (IBAction)PlayGameBT:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)ViewScoresBT:(id)sender;

-(void)AddNewScore :(NSString *)userName :(int)score;//for PlayGame see .m

@end
```

---

this is the code for MainMenuScreen.m

```
#import "MainMenuScreen.h"
#import "PlayGame.h"
#import "ImageTest.h"

@interface MainMenuScreen ()

@end

@implementation MainMenuScreen

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//------------------------------------Variables------------------------------------

PlayGame *playGame;//PlayGameObject

NSMutableArray *gameDataArray;//Game Data Array (A array storying multable ImageTest Objects)

NSMutableArray *scoresArray;//<-------This need to go to view scores

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//----------------------------------Constructors-----------------------------------

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    scoresArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [scoresArray addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bob",[NSNumber numberWithInt:134],nil]];//testData
    [scoresArray addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Roger",[NSNumber numberWithInt:12],nil]];//testData
    [scoresArray addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ben",[NSNumber numberWithInt:34],nil]];//testData

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//----------------------------------Add New Score----------------------------------
//a setter Method so Play Game can add the user name and score to the scoresArray
-(void)AddNewScore :(NSString *)userName :(int)score
{
    //adds user name and score to the array
    if (scoresArray != nil)
    {
        /*NSMutableArray *nameAndScore = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [nameAndScore addObject:userName];
        [nameAndScore addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:score]];//int needs to be converted before storing in an array
        [scoresArray addObject:nameAndScore];*/

        [scoresArray addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:userName,[NSNumber numberWithInt:score],nil]];


        for(NSMutableArray *m in scoresArray)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@%@", m[0],m[1]);//prints out the array in logs to make sure it is working
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all there are different possibilities. Segues allow you to pass information to the next view during a transition. To do this you'll want a property on the ScoresScreen that you can assign to your array in MainMenuScreen. Second I suggest you show us a bit of code so we can better understand what you want and help you understand what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two or three different ways. In addition to what Ryan already commented.

1. You could pass it on from the MainMenuScreen when creating the ScoresScreen but before presenting the ScoresScreen.
2. You could make the Array a property of the MainMenuScreen that can be retrieved from the any class importing it.
3. You could have a seperate DataManager kind of class (usualy a singleton class) that manages the Array and both classes could get the array from there.

Also: When importing you should import the .h file, not the .m like you put in your post, not sure if that was a typo or a mistake in your code. If you have a method or property in the MainMenuScreen that would return the array it needs to be declared in the header file (.h) through which the class importing it knows of it's existence.

Comment: Thankyou for the quick responses...it was a mistake I tried doing import "MainMenuScreen.h" and then when I called the array and displayed it - it just said "null null", so its saying its empty.

Comment: @tjose Maybe you can show some code on how you fill the Array with data? It is very hard to figure out why the array would say "null null" without seeing any code.

Comment: Can you try updating that in your post instead of the comment, it is quite unreadable, and should be part of your question, not my anwser.

Comment: Yes sorry, first time using this =/

Comment: It is showing null because you create the array in viewDidLoad, this method is never called if you just init a MainMenuScreen without actually presenting it like you would from ScoresScreen

Comment: Hmm...Sorry to ask, but im still trying to grasp what these different views are...How would I present it in ScoresScreen properly then please?

Comment: Sorry IM getting confused...When testing the actual app it works..When I look on Xcode it says the output in the bottom right box and it seems to be working fine. I think that array is working fine, its just to get the data from the array and display it into a different class

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining an array property in second ScoresScreen.h file like:

```
@interface ScoresScreen : UIViewController {
   NSArray *array;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign)NSArray *array;
```

in .m file synthesize it like

```
@synthesize array;
```

Now in MainMenuScreen.m just assign it

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   ScoresScreen *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
   controller.array = yourArray;
}
```

**Edit** 
.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ScoresScreen : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
     NSMutableArray *scoresArray;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *scoresArray; //Added this line

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ScoresScreen.h"
#import "MainMenuScreen.h"

@interface ScoresScreen ()

@end

@implementation ScoresScreen
@synthesize scoresArray; //Added this line
NSMutableArray *TestScoresArray;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   ...
....
....
```

your .m

```
#import "MainMenuScreen.h"
#import "PlayGame.h"
#import "ImageTest.h"

@interface MainMenuScreen ()

@end

@implementation MainMenuScreen

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//------------------------------------Variables------------------------------------

PlayGame *playGame;//PlayGameObject

NSMutableArray *gameDataArray;//Game Data Array (A array storying multable ImageTest Objects)

NSMutableArray *scoresArray;//<-------This need to go to view scores

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//----------------------------------Constructors-----------------------------------

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    scoresArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [scoresArray addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bob",[NSNumber numberWithInt:134],nil]];//testData
    [scoresArray addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Roger",[NSNumber numberWithInt:12],nil]];//testData
    [scoresArray addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ben",[NSNumber numberWithInt:34],nil]];//testData

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//----------------------------------Add New Score----------------------------------
//a setter Method so Play Game can add the user name and score to the scoresArray
-(void)AddNewScore :(NSString *)userName :(int)score
{
    //adds user name and score to the array
    if (scoresArray != nil)
    {
        /*NSMutableArray *nameAndScore = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [nameAndScore addObject:userName];
        [nameAndScore addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:score]];//int needs to be converted before storing in an array
        [scoresArray addObject:nameAndScore];*/

        [scoresArray addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:userName,[NSNumber numberWithInt:score],nil]];


        for(NSMutableArray *m in scoresArray)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@%@", m[0],m[1]);//prints out the array in logs to make sure it is working
        }
    }
}


    //added this method
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
       ScoresScreen *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
       controller.array = yourArray;
    }
```

Comment: If you actually create a property then you should use the setArray method. With your scorescreen code (controller.array) you are actually accessing the NSMutableArray and not the NSArray property.

Comment: Thanks Inder, but what does "ScoresScreen *controller" <-- mean please? What does controller do?

Comment: I tried doing what you done but its just coming up with errors for me

Comment: @ophychius NSMutableArray was by mistake it's NSArray.

Comment: Yes Im using .xib and storyboard. im displaying the array on the storyboard

Comment: There is still no need to create that Array, nor should you use (controller.array) after creating the property. The point of creating the property is to get a getter and setter for your variable.

Comment: @ophychius so you think `controller.array = arr;` and `[controller setArray:arr];`

Comment: If you create a public or protected variable like you do, no getter or setter are needed, since access is open already. If you create a property to get your getter and setter functions, any use of the variable from outside the class should go through the getter and setter methods. Thus [controller setArray: arr]; and arr = [controller array];

Comment: @ophychius first of all default access is protected. you can't access `array` outside the class. Secondly you can't access instance variable using `.` dot operator. Whenever you use `.` it means you are accessing it using properties.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Looking at my code above, how would you get the array from MainMenuScreen.m to ScoresScreen.m?

Comment: @tjose put `prepareForSegue` method in your MainMenuScreen.m. if you already have that method then put your code in it.

Comment: Thats my question, because Im not sure how the syntax works and where to put these commands that your telling me to put in (im a beginner at Objective C)

Comment: @InderKumarRathore It seems I got things mixed up and you are right. I would still prefer using bracket notation just for clarity's sake, but you are correct.

Comment: @ophychius No prob :) it happens if you are using multiple languages at very frequently. As I'm working on c# so I forgot the default access of ivar in obj-c so I searched it and told you the same ;)

Comment: @tjose For that I need your .h & .m files of your two controller. I don't know why it's difficult for you.

Comment: sorry, but the code for both .h and .m are now above. Thankyou very much

Comment: @tjose added lines and method at the end. I have added comment there.

Comment: Thankyou INder, I used that code you kindly gave to me, but its coming up with an error on the @synthesize scoresArray; (from ScoresScreen.m) - The error is "Existing ivar 'scoresArray' for_weak property 'scoresArray' must be _weak" - In the code both propertys are 'weak', so I dont see why its coming up with an error?

Comment: Also under MainMenuScreen.m under this line of code - - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender - The error says 'prepareForSegue' is undeclared. What would I have to declare as?

Comment: then make it strong property `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *scoresArray;`

Comment: Ah thankyou! That worked when I changed it to strong...But I still have the error for : Also under MainMenuScreen.m under this line of code - - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender - The error says 'prepareForSegue' is undeclared. What would I have to declare as?

Comment: Yes declare in .h file. I don't know why it's showing error. It shouldn't throw any error messages, though in pervious version of compiler it shows a warning.

Comment: @tjose sorry I defined that method inside a method. Now edited again. Moved method definition out side.

Comment: Hi Inder, thanks for that but its still coming up with an error after I put it outside of the brackets...THe error is saying "Use of unidentified identifier 'controller'...I dont understand why it keeps coming up with errors?

Answer (score 0):

Move the array to your app delegate. To access the app delegate from any class, do:

`#import "NameOfYourAppDelegate.h"`

in the top of the file, and

`NameOfYourAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate`

where you want to use it.